# Somar coluna LISTVIEW

Tags: delphi

Tenho um componente listview em meu projeto, e nele consta uma Coluna com vários valores inseridos. Alguém tem ideia de como posso somar uma coluna inteira do listview que so consta valores do tipo:

```
 300,00
 52,00
 100,00
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda....

Comment: Não faça a soma no listview. Some ao inserir no listview **à partir das variáveis** que populam os itens no loop, depois você só adiciona a linha do total, se quiser exibir na tela (ou usa o valor em outra parte do software, como desejar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue parte do código fonte de um form que criei para testar a solução.

```
type
  TfrmPrincipal = class(TForm)
    lvLista: TListView;
    btnSoma: TButton;
    procedure btnSomaClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmPrincipal: TfrmPrincipal;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmPrincipal.btnSomaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  dSoma : double;
  i : integer;
begin
  dSoma := 0;
  for i := 0 to MyListView.Items.Count - 1 do begin
    dSoma := dSoma + StrToFloatDef( MyListView.Items[ i ].Caption, 0 );
  end;
  ShowMessage( FloatToStr( dSoma ) );
end;
```

Testado em Delphi7.

O ".Caption" acessa o valor da primeira coluna.
Caso seja necessário acessar outras, deve ser utilizado ".SubItems[x]", lembrando que "x" é igual ao "número da coluna" menos 2.

Exemplos:

- A segunda coluna do ListView é o primeiro sub-iten e este tem índice
  "0" (zero)
- A sétima coluna do ListView, seria acessado com    ".SubItems[5]"

Comment: Obrigado @Anselmo, eu preciso somar um determinado SUBITEM, tentei dessa forma não deu certo, o que eu fiz de errado: dSoma := dSoma + StrToFloatDef( LV.Items[ i ].SubItems[7], 0 );

Comment: A sintaxe do seu comando está correta. O único erro que posso imaginar está no índice dos sub-itens, no seu caso, o "7". Os "SubItems" começam a ser contados a partir da segunda coluna e começar com índice "0" (zero). Assim, para acessar, por exemplo, a sétima coluna você precisaria usar `LV.Items[ i ].SubItems[5]`

Comment: Perfeito @Anselmo, obrigado!

Comment: Nossa! Perfeito! Explicação genial.